# Android - How to ListView Fast Filter instantly

Tags: android, listview, dictionary, android-cursoradapter

I have a dictionary database that contain more than 300,000 words, using cursoradapter to fill in ListView. When filter one word in ListView, the sotware delays, is there any way to filter word instantly?

This is code of the Main

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db=new WordDbAdapter(this);
    db.openDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.getAllWord();
    adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item, cursor,new            String[] {"word"},new int[] {R.id.title}, 0);


    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    filter=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

This is code of the Database:

```
public Cursor getAllWord()
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {


        String sql="select rowid _id,word from anh_viet";
         cursor=mdb.rawQuery(sql, null);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return cursor;

}
public Cursor filterWord(String key)
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {


        String sql="select rowid _id,word from anh_viet where word like '"+key+"%'";
         cursor=mdb.rawQuery(sql, null);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return cursor;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never write a query like this:

`String sql="select rowid _id,word from anh_viet where word like '"+key+"%'";`

Its insecure (you can have SQL injection) and it requires the db to reparse and optimize the query each time.  Instead use a bind variable for the key.  That will allow it to cache the search (speeding it up) and prevent any possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: Could you please explain me more detail?